# Update Query using the Objective C Wrapper for sqlite

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, wrapper

Hey I am using the http://th30z.netsons.org/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper/ 
wrapper .

My code is this :

```
    - (IBAction)UpdateButtonPressed:(id)sender 
    {


        Sqlite *sqlite = [[Sqlite alloc] init];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Money"ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (![sqlite open:writableDBPath])
            return;


        NSArray *query = [sqlite executeQuery:@"UPDATE UserAccess SET Answer ='Positano';"];
            NSDictionary *dict = [query objectAtIndex:2];
            NSString *itemValue = [dict objectForKey:@"Answer"];
            NSLog(@"%@",itemValue);
}
```

Answer is the Column name , UserAccess the table name .
the column is at 3rd place in the table

What am I doing wrong why is it crashing ???

Comment: I should be able to update it from the UITextfiled i.e updatefield.text >> if the user types positano then update into the DB . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update query does not return any results. You will typically use `objectAtIndex` after executing a SELECT query, but it won't work with UPDATE.

Comment: [sqlite executeQuery:@"UPDATE UserAccess SET Answer ='Positano';"];

NSArray *query2 = [sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT Answer FROM UserAccess;"];
 NSDictionary *dict = [query2 objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *itemValue = [dict objectForKey:@"Answer"];
 NSLog(@"%@",itemValue);


This worked for me thanks ... how stupid am I need to go through sql again . 
Do you know how can I accept it from UITextField >> updatefield.text

Answer (score 1):

```
@"UPDATE UserAccess SET Answer ='Positano';"]; 
NSArray *query2 = [sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT Answer FROM UserAccess;"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [query2 objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *itemValue = [dict objectForKey:@"Answer"];
```